# Makfile generates both `(.text+0x0): multiple definition` and `(.text+0x44): undefined reference to` errors when linking .o objects

Tags: c, makefile

I have the following makefile with which I cannot manage to link the objects into the final executable, although it builds the individual object files fine. It outputs both `(.text+0x0): multiple definition` and `(.text+0x44): undefined reference to` errors when building the main target.

```
# Set compiler
CC = gcc

# Include headers 
INC_HDR := -I. -IAPI/core -IAPI/platform

# Define final executable 
EXE := driver 

# List source
SRC := $(wildcard API/core/*.c) \
        $(wildcard API/platform/*.c) \
        main.c 

# List headers
HDR := $(wildcard API/core/*.h) \
        $(wildcard API/platform/*.h) 

# Derive objects
OBJ := $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(SRC))

# Set flags 
CPPFLAGS := $(INC_HDR) -MMD -MP # -I is a preprocessor flag, not a compiler flag -MMD -MP
CFLAGS   := -Wall           # some warnings about bad code
LDFLAGS  := -L.             # -L is a linker flag
LDLIBS   := -lm             # Left empty if no libs are needed

.PHONY: all clean 

all: $(EXE)

$(EXE): $(OBJ) 
    @echo Linking $@
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(LDLIBS) $^ -o $@ 

$(OBJ): $(SRC) $(HDR)
    @echo Building $@ 
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    @find . -type f -name '*.o' -delete
    @find . -type f -name '*.d' -delete
```

This question is quite close to other posts but I haven't been able to find what the problem is so far.

As requested, the output of `make clean all` is:

```
Building API/core/VL53L1X_calibration.o
gcc -I. -IAPI/core -IAPI/platform -MMD -MP  -Wall                -c API/core/VL53L1X_calibration.c -o API/core/VL53L1X_calibration.o
Building API/core/VL53L1X_api.o
gcc -I. -IAPI/core -IAPI/platform -MMD -MP  -Wall                -c API/core/VL53L1X_calibration.c -o API/core/VL53L1X_api.o
Building API/platform/vl53l1_platform.o
gcc -I. -IAPI/core -IAPI/platform -MMD -MP  -Wall                -c API/core/VL53L1X_calibration.c -o API/platform/vl53l1_platform.o
Building main.o
gcc -I. -IAPI/core -IAPI/platform -MMD -MP  -Wall                -c API/core/VL53L1X_calibration.c -o main.o
Linking driver
gcc -I. -IAPI/core -IAPI/platform -MMD -MP  -Wall                -lm              API/core/VL53L1X_calibration.o API/core/VL53L1X_api.o API/platform/vl53l1_platform.o main.o -o driver 
API/core/VL53L1X_api.o: In function `VL53L1X_CalibrateOffset':
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `VL53L1X_CalibrateOffset'
API/core/VL53L1X_calibration.o:VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
API/core/VL53L1X_api.o: In function `VL53L1X_CalibrateXtalk':
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x170): multiple definition of `VL53L1X_CalibrateXtalk'
API/core/VL53L1X_calibration.o:VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x170): first defined here
API/platform/vl53l1_platform.o: In function `VL53L1X_CalibrateOffset':
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `VL53L1X_CalibrateOffset'
API/core/VL53L1X_calibration.o:VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
API/platform/vl53l1_platform.o: In function `VL53L1X_CalibrateXtalk':
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x170): multiple definition of `VL53L1X_CalibrateXtalk'
API/core/VL53L1X_calibration.o:VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x170): first defined here
main.o: In function `VL53L1X_CalibrateOffset':
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `VL53L1X_CalibrateOffset'
API/core/VL53L1X_calibration.o:VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
main.o: In function `VL53L1X_CalibrateXtalk':
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x170): multiple definition of `VL53L1X_CalibrateXtalk'
API/core/VL53L1X_calibration.o:VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x170): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
API/core/VL53L1X_calibration.o: In function `VL53L1X_CalibrateOffset':
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x44): undefined reference to `VL53L1_WrWord'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x5c): undefined reference to `VL53L1_WrWord'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x74): undefined reference to `VL53L1_WrWord'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x82): undefined reference to `VL53L1X_StartRanging'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0xa3): undefined reference to `VL53L1X_CheckForDataReady'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0xc0): undefined reference to `VL53L1X_GetDistance'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0xce): undefined reference to `VL53L1X_ClearInterrupt'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0xfa): undefined reference to `VL53L1X_StopRanging'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x14f): undefined reference to `VL53L1_WrWord'
API/core/VL53L1X_calibration.o: In function `VL53L1X_CalibrateXtalk':
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x1cf): undefined reference to `VL53L1_WrWord'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x1dd): undefined reference to `VL53L1X_StartRanging'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x201): undefined reference to `VL53L1X_CheckForDataReady'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x21e): undefined reference to `VL53L1X_GetSignalRate'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x233): undefined reference to `VL53L1X_GetDistance'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x241): undefined reference to `VL53L1X_ClearInterrupt'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x26f): undefined reference to `VL53L1X_GetSpadNb'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x2c3): undefined reference to `VL53L1X_StopRanging'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x376): undefined reference to `VL53L1_WrWord'
API/core/VL53L1X_api.o: In function `VL53L1X_CalibrateOffset':
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x44): undefined reference to `VL53L1_WrWord'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x5c): undefined reference to `VL53L1_WrWord'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x74): undefined reference to `VL53L1_WrWord'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x82): undefined reference to `VL53L1X_StartRanging'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0xa3): undefined reference to `VL53L1X_CheckForDataReady'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0xc0): undefined reference to `VL53L1X_GetDistance'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0xce): undefined reference to `VL53L1X_ClearInterrupt'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0xfa): undefined reference to `VL53L1X_StopRanging'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x14f): undefined reference to `VL53L1_WrWord'
API/core/VL53L1X_api.o: In function `VL53L1X_CalibrateXtalk':
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x1cf): undefined reference to `VL53L1_WrWord'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x1dd): undefined reference to `VL53L1X_StartRanging'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x201): undefined reference to `VL53L1X_CheckForDataReady'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x21e): undefined reference to `VL53L1X_GetSignalRate'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x233): undefined reference to `VL53L1X_GetDistance'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x241): undefined reference to `VL53L1X_ClearInterrupt'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x26f): undefined reference to `VL53L1X_GetSpadNb'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x2c3): undefined reference to `VL53L1X_StopRanging'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x376): undefined reference to `VL53L1_WrWord'
API/platform/vl53l1_platform.o: In function `VL53L1X_CalibrateOffset':
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x44): undefined reference to `VL53L1_WrWord'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x5c): undefined reference to `VL53L1_WrWord'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x74): undefined reference to `VL53L1_WrWord'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x82): undefined reference to `VL53L1X_StartRanging'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0xa3): undefined reference to `VL53L1X_CheckForDataReady'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0xc0): undefined reference to `VL53L1X_GetDistance'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0xce): undefined reference to `VL53L1X_ClearInterrupt'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0xfa): undefined reference to `VL53L1X_StopRanging'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x14f): undefined reference to `VL53L1_WrWord'
API/platform/vl53l1_platform.o: In function `VL53L1X_CalibrateXtalk':
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x1cf): undefined reference to `VL53L1_WrWord'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x1dd): undefined reference to `VL53L1X_StartRanging'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x201): undefined reference to `VL53L1X_CheckForDataReady'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x21e): undefined reference to `VL53L1X_GetSignalRate'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x233): undefined reference to `VL53L1X_GetDistance'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x241): undefined reference to `VL53L1X_ClearInterrupt'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x26f): undefined reference to `VL53L1X_GetSpadNb'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x2c3): undefined reference to `VL53L1X_StopRanging'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x376): undefined reference to `VL53L1_WrWord'
main.o: In function `VL53L1X_CalibrateOffset':
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x44): undefined reference to `VL53L1_WrWord'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x5c): undefined reference to `VL53L1_WrWord'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x74): undefined reference to `VL53L1_WrWord'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x82): undefined reference to `VL53L1X_StartRanging'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0xa3): undefined reference to `VL53L1X_CheckForDataReady'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0xc0): undefined reference to `VL53L1X_GetDistance'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0xce): undefined reference to `VL53L1X_ClearInterrupt'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0xfa): undefined reference to `VL53L1X_StopRanging'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x14f): undefined reference to `VL53L1_WrWord'
main.o: In function `VL53L1X_CalibrateXtalk':
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x1cf): undefined reference to `VL53L1_WrWord'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x1dd): undefined reference to `VL53L1X_StartRanging'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x201): undefined reference to `VL53L1X_CheckForDataReady'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x21e): undefined reference to `VL53L1X_GetSignalRate'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x233): undefined reference to `VL53L1X_GetDistance'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x241): undefined reference to `VL53L1X_ClearInterrupt'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x26f): undefined reference to `VL53L1X_GetSpadNb'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x2c3): undefined reference to `VL53L1X_StopRanging'
VL53L1X_calibration.c:(.text+0x376): undefined reference to `VL53L1_WrWord'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:33: recipe for target 'driver' failed
make: *** [driver] Error 1
```

Comment: Those look like errors from `ld`, not `make`.

Comment: Please show the *complete* output of `make clean all`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at these lines:

```
Building API/core/VL53L1X_calibration.o
gcc -I. -IAPI/core -IAPI/platform -MMD -MP  -Wall -c API/core/VL53L1X_calibration.c -o API/core/VL53L1X_calibration.o
Building API/core/VL53L1X_api.o
gcc -I. -IAPI/core -IAPI/platform -MMD -MP  -Wall -c API/core/VL53L1X_calibration.c -o API/core/VL53L1X_api.o
Building API/platform/vl53l1_platform.o
gcc -I. -IAPI/core -IAPI/platform -MMD -MP  -Wall -c API/core/VL53L1X_calibration.c -o API/platform/vl53l1_platform.o
Building main.o
gcc -I. -IAPI/core -IAPI/platform -MMD -MP  -Wall -c API/core/VL53L1X_calibration.c -o main.o
```

You'll see that you're using the *same* source file to create each object file.  So anything defined in that function will be defined multiple times and anything that's not will be undefined.

This is because of how you defined the target for object files:

```
$(OBJ): $(SRC) $(HDR)
```

It should be:

```
%.o: %.c $(HDR)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @dbush, I did not pay enough attention to the error message!